# Ruby: BigDecimal: a class and a method at the same time?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, callable

```
require bigdecimal
BigDecimal.class     # => Class
```

So, `BigDecimal` is a class.

But at the same time, `BigDecimal` can be invoked like a method:

```
BigDecimal("42.0")   # => 0.42e2
```

What is the mechanism behind it? How can I see that `BigDecimal` is callable? And how can I make my own class constants callable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is a class, but it is also a method defined in the [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html) module.

Methods that are defined in the Kernel doesn't have to have a receiver to be called, as the `Kernel` module is mixed with the `Object` class.

> [From the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html): The Kernel module is included by class Object, so its methods are available in every Ruby object.

Ruby knows `Array.new` and `Array(1)` are different things because constants ([classes and modules are constants](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html)) do not receive arguments.

```
class Abc
end

def Abc
  puts 'Method called'
end

Abc()
#=> Method called

Abc
#=> Abc (Class)
```

As [Matz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto) once said:

> I'm trying to make Ruby natural, not simple. Ruby is simple in appearance, but is very complex inside, just like our human body.

Comment: So, I can see that there is a method `BigDecimal` (besides the class `BigDecimal`) by trying `method(:BigDecimal) # => #<Method: main.BigDecimal>`.